# DOMElement absolutely exists, but PHP gives fatal error saying it doesn't, right after saying it does

Tags: php, dom

Consider the following code:

```
$xmlstr = new DOMDocument();
$xmlstr->loadXML($text, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);
$xp = new DOMXPath($xmlstr);
$xp->registerNamespace("w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");
$contents = $xp->query("//w:p");
foreach ($contents as $node)
{
        $children = $node->childNodes;
}
```

This goes well for hundreds of nodes, and then suddenly:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Couldn't fetch DOMElement. Node no longer exists
```

This error is generated in the line saying:

```
$children = $node->childNodes;
```

As you can see nothing is processed: foreach $contents as $node can only give a $node if the $node exists, yet the $node suddenly doesn't exist right after PHP yelled it existed. This is not possible. What is going on here?

Checking whether the node has children beforehand, of even checking (if ($node) does not change anything. Trying to catch doesn't change anything either:

```
try {
     $children = $node->childNodes;
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
     echo 'Okay, that didn't work<br>';
}
```

still generates the same error. The error isn't caught.

When I do a print_r before actually doing anything with the node, it says:
DOMElement ( )
I.e. the node is void.

I've come a bit closer. The node disappears because text in a previous node is modified incorrectly. If I modify all nodes except node number 195, node 196 is read without errors. If I modify node number 195 too, node 196 suddenly disappears. Node 195 is more than 118.000 characters long. I wonder if there is some kind of limitation? If I export its contents to a file, the string is not cut off, so I wonder if $node->textContent has a limit?

Comment: `DOMXPath()` expects DOM not String!  https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.construct

Comment: You cannot catch an error exception with `catch (Exception $e)`; you need `catch (Error $e)` or `catch(Throwable $e)` for that. More than that, fatal errors cannot be caught. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php

Comment: @MarkusZeller Apologies, that name is deceptive. I've now added the two lines in front of it. It's not a string. And as said, this works for hundreds of nodes before.

Comment: @ZoliSzabó Okay, that explains why the catch doesn't work, but still, that doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Hard to debug without seeing the DOM.

Comment: I've come a bit closer. The node disappears because text in a previous node is modified incorrectly. If I modify all nodes except node number 195, node 196 is read without errors. If I modify node number 195 too, node 196 suddenly disappears. Node 195 is more than 118.000 characters long. I wonder if there is some kind of limitation? If I export its contents to a file, the string is not cut off, so I wonder if $node->textContent has a limit?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that w:p nodes can actually have other w:p nodes as their descendants (paragraphs containing embedded tables containing rows containing cells containing new paragraphs, to be precise). This resulted in two issues: the function imported Paragraphs enclosed by other Paragraphs twice, once as part of the enclosing Paragraph, and once as the enclosed Paragraph itself. The enclosing Paragraphs were also way too long (the PHP code broke at a length of 118.000 characters), so that text inserted to Nodes would actually break them, resulting in fatal errors that were only detected as soon as we tried opening the **next** node.

The HTML contents of each node are actually parsed and simplified if we have detected innerHTML in a node. If a node is empty or if we ignore it, the modified contents are not written to said node. I have added an extra line in the code: when w:p contents inside a node are now detected, said node is simply ignored. This way we will never process w:p nodes if they contain other w:p nodes.

```
    $innerHTML .= $child->ownerDocument->saveXML($child);
```

changed into

```
if (!str_contains($child->ownerDocument->saveXML($child), '<w:p'))
{
    $innerHTML .= $child->ownerDocument->saveXML($child);
}
```